# Kubuntu boots slowly when using USB 3.0 hub

Tags: linux, boot, usb, usb-3, kubuntu

When booting my Dell XPS 13 (2013, L322X) with kubuntu 15.04 with Plasma 5 and nothing attached i get a start up time of ca 9 seconds.

When i attach my USB 3.0 hub I get ca 30 seconds. 
That is even when nothing is attached to the hub. 
The hub is a deltaco WS-UH3047. 
Running 'dmesg' i get the important lines:

```
[    6.662579] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[    6.662583] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   11.673909] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   11.673918] usb 1-1: hub failed to enable device, error -62
[   11.785996] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   16.685187] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[   16.685191] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   16.889344] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[   21.696530] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   21.696540] usb 1-1: hub failed to enable device, error -62
```

Attaching the hub post boot is fine and everything works immediately in that case. But I'd prefer not to unplug it at every reboot. The problem is not present in Windows 10 on the same computer, or in standard Ubuntu 14.04 on a different machine (thinkpad X61).

Comment: Do you have access to a different USB Hub, based on the log, the device is not behaving itself.

Comment: No, not really...

Comment: You are connecting this device to a USB 3.0 port or USB 2.0 port?

Comment: To a 3.0, if I'm not misstaken. I think this laptop has only 3.0 ports (and only two of them, thus hub)

Comment: When i tried using regular ubuntu it was on a thinkpad X61, which has only 2.0. In that case there where no problems.

Comment: What worked on your old hardware is not really helpful unless it was the same physical hub, if that is the case, update your question.  You need to verify what type of port you are plugging it into then update your question.

Comment: I used the same USB 3.0 Hub on the old computer, but on a USB 2.0 port, in ubuntu, and that worked out well. Ill update with that info.